# Getting values live from a logfile into a string for calculations using Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a logfile `forces.dat` which is continuously updated with force values, one per line. The file looks like this:

```
1.190476e-05    ((6.882904e-04 3.133477e-04 -5.099806e+02) (8.595292e-08 1.222541e-08 -1.198233e-04) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00)) ((-1.555656e-05 2.712085e-05 2.977440e-06) (4.087154e-09 1.635450e-08 -2.306391e-08) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00))
```

The first number is the time followed by the force values.

I want to calculate with some of the values as the file is growing. I can read the file live with:

```
import time

def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
          time.sleep(0.1)
          continue
        yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open("forces.dat","r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)

    for line in loglines:
        print line
```

(http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/)

I won't to get number 1, 11, 12 and 13 and assign them a string so I can use them to calculate some values.

I can work with

```
line = line.replace()
```

but

```
line = line.rsplit('\t', 1)[0]
line = line[:12]
```

is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data can be parsed using regular expressions, with the help of python's `re` module. E.g.

```
import re

# Suppose line has the data in your question
line = '1.190476e-05    ((6.882904e-04 3.133477e-04 -5.099806e+02) (8.595292e-08 1.222541e-08 -1.198233e-04) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00)) ((-1.555656e-05 2.712085e-05 2.977440e-06) (4.087154e-09 1.635450e-08 -2.306391e-08) (0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00))'

numbers = re.findall('[0-9]\.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]{2}', line)
```

`numbers` contains the data below, the numbers in a simple (to use) list:

```
['1.190476e-05',
 '6.882904e-04',
 '3.133477e-04',
 '5.099806e+02',
 '8.595292e-08',
 '1.222541e-08',
 '1.198233e-04',
 '0.000000e+00',
 '0.000000e+00',
 '0.000000e+00',
 '1.555656e-05',
 '2.712085e-05',
 '2.977440e-06',
 '4.087154e-09',
 '1.635450e-08',
 '2.306391e-08',
 '0.000000e+00',
 '0.000000e+00',
 '0.000000e+00']
```

If you are not familar with regular expressions, let me disect it:

```
\d     # Match any digit between 0 and 9, followed by
\.     # ... a literal dot character, followed by
\d+    # ... one or more digits, followed by
e      # ... a literal character 'e', followed by
[+-]   # ... a single occurrence of either '+' or '-', followed by
\d{2}  # ... exactly two digits.
```

The full reference of the supported regex syntax is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).